# HTML icon duplicated even though written once

Tags: html, web, icons, font-awesome

I was trying to link a URL to an icon, but it somehow made 4 icons although I only wrote once. This is the part where caused the problem

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/ca04587938.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="navBar">
    <div class="logoBox">
      <a href="https://www.youtube.com">
        <i class="fa fa-youtube-square" />
      </a>
      <span class="title">Youtube</span>
    </div>
    <div class="iconBox"></div>
  </nav>
</body>
```

And, this is the result

[image: and here's what I get]

Comment: Why is the stylesheet `link` linking to a javascript file?

Comment: I was trying out something by myself.. But that line doesn't affect the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The icon appears multiple times since you forgot to close your `<i>` tag.

So instead of:

```
<i class="fa fa-youtube-square">
```

write:

```
<i class="fa fa-youtube-square"></i>
```

Comment: I feel ashamed and stupid, thank you so much

Comment: Glad to hear it works for you! Please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark :)